# Partially capital section in an article

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, capitalization

I want to make the section name in capital letters, but only partially, cause i need my name and surname in small letters. However reffering to the ToC, the whole section has to be written in small letters.

```
\section{INTRODUCTION (John Smith)}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `\section[introduction (john smith)]{INTRODUCTION (John Smith)}` what about the running heads?

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you very much! I've been looking for the solution for hours, and thought it has to be more complicated, however sometimes the easiest ways are the best. What do you mean  by mentioning the running heads?

Comment: Depending on the page style (`headings`, `myheadings`, ...) section/chapter titles can appear in the header line of a page.

Comment: It would be nice, if the headers didn't contain the name and the surname, only the name of the section.

Comment: `\lhead{Section {\nouppercase{\thesection. \textit{\leftmark}}}}` 
It looks like this right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the optional argument for `\section[<ToC>]{<title>}` to set something different in the `<ToC>` and the actual `<title>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[introduction (john smith)]{INTRODUCTION (John Smith)}
\sectionmark{John Smith}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

If, in addition to different content in the `<ToC>` and `<title>`, you also want something different in the headers (when using `\pagestyle{headings}`, say), you can specify this manually via `\sectionmark{<heading>}` *immediately* after `\section`:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
    \markright{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\m@ne \thesection \quad \fi #1}}%
}
\makeatother

% ...

\section[introduction (john smith)]{INTRODUCTION (John Smith)}
\sectionmark{John Smith}
```

I've added an update to `\sectionmark` as well, which removes the default `\MakeUppercase` that is inserted.

[image]